# Which is the best way to download database initial data to an iOS app?

Tags: mysql, ios, sqlite, ios5

I am developing an application that on the user's first login must download a lot of data from my server and store it in a local database in my iOS app.

In my server I am using MySQL. And I need to download 70MB... to my iOS app to use this data locally, having or not connection.

What's the best way to download this data? XML zipped? Export to a SQLite file, zip this file, and download?

Can you recommend any approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the database on the server is dynamic; A good approach is to build an API for accessing the Database data on the server, you can build an API through PHP and have the app just read the responses of data as JSON or XML.

Another approach if the database is static and wont update frequently is to add the SQL database to the IOS app as an SQLite database and just run local sql queries on the app.

Comment: The data will be semi dinamyc ;) I mean, there will be updates and new records, but the data need to be locally so the user can use the app having or not connection. Every x time the user will be notified about updates (new records and updates) so he could download the new data to the app. That's why i'm not sure about request to server using json or xml.

Comment: Then SQLite is the way to go :) , you can check the latest version of the database each time the user launches the app, if theres a newer one just download and overwrite the sqlite db file on the ios app.

Comment: So you say, for example that I can make a script that exports my MySQL database to SQLite (for example once a day) and zip it. Then when the user makes his first login download this zip, expand it, and start working with it?

Comment: Yeah you can zip the sqlite db on the server then download from the IOS app and unzip it, Or you can just download the sqlite from the server directly without zipping/unzipping. You can keep track of the current version of the DATABASE using NSUSERDEFAULTS and compare it against a text file on the server to see if theres a newer version available for download.

Comment: a sample of how to download the DB

NSData *fetchedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL          URLWithString:@"http://www.myserver.com/files/DBName.sqlite"]]];
NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDire ctory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DBName.sqlite"];
[fetchedData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

Comment: Excellent!!! Thanks for the help :) And last question, dumb question, isn't too much 70MB to download, if I dwonload the whole table?

Comment: Yeah thats a big file, a daily download of 70 MB would bother a lot of users. Is it worth having the app in offline mode? if its absolutely necessary to have the app in offline mode i suggest you update the database every few days or weeks.

Answer (score 0):

We use web services and SOAP for transferring data from server to device. You should look into SOAP and REST web services. You basically get back xml which you can parse and use to create appropriate objects.

Although this may be a little too much for what you're trying to do, it's worth looking into.

Also, data can be stored in an SQLite Database, which is supported on most mobile platforms.

Comment: I was thinking about this and download the data divided by the tables. I mean, first download table A (10MB), then download table B (12MB), etc. But, 10Mb isn't too much data for a WS call? On the other I can't put the data in the bundle because, I need that when the user logins in first time he could download the database with the last records included. If I bundle the database, I would need to upload the app to the AppStore every x time so the app cames with last data included.

Comment: SOAP is far too bloated for such simple tasks - I would recommend JSON instead.

Comment: Well the data and the database are two different things. You could always bundle the database tables (empty of course) and just populate the data later with the download call. Only problem is if you plan on modifying the fields in any way you may have to resubmit your binary. Also whether transferring data by WS or some other way 10 MB is still a lot of data. Till mentioned JSON, which is a lot slimmer than XML so that's a good bet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can export it to SQLite, zip it and download using [AFNetworking.](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

```
NSString *yourFileURL=@"http://yourFileURL.zip";
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:yourFileURL]];
AFURLConnectionOperation *operation =   [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

NSString *cacheDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
                          (NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [cacheDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                      @"youFile.zip"];

operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:filePath append:NO];

[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
   //show here your downloading progress if needed
}];

[operation setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"File successfully downloaded");
}];

[operation start];
```