# How to download and save server database to client (iOS app) for further operation?

Tags: ios, oracle, sqlite, core-data, relational-database

My iOS app needs to download data from the server (just once when the app starts). The downloaded data will be used by the app for further operations.

**Server end:** I use Oracle server (11g) and Oracle SQL developer to make database.

**Client end:** I use objective-c to write my iOS app.

**What have I done so far?**

The table at the database of the server is populated with the data sent from the client (iPhone). The client also receives data from the server (contents of the table) in text format. Hence, the database is created and connected to the server, also server/client data exchange is working perfectly.

**Nature of database:**

The data stored in the server is a survey data, so it needs to be stored in the server database such that other clients can access and use it. Moreover, when the survey is completed, the data is not updated anymore, i.e. my database is static. The size of data may be of few MBs.

As far as I know, for database issues, we can use a .plist file, CoreData, and SQLite in iOS. A very good example of SQLite in iOS is given at [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_sqlite_database.htm) tutorial. A thread at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249512/which-is-the-best-way-to-download-database-initial-data-to-an-ios-app) link has suggested to use SQLite database and just run local SQL queries on the app. If I follow this suggestion, is the knowledge of socket streaming be enough for this operation? Is there any other better ways to solve my problem? Could somebody provide any links/threads about storing data in iOS using CoreData/SQLite?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use Realm framework to save data in database .It will help you in having simple data objects.No complex queries or table. 
https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/

Comment: https://github.com/martinrybak/SQLClient